# XCode prerequisite version check failed? Unable to package app with Intune Packager

Tags: xcode9, intune

**Edit**: It appears the latest Release Notes from Apple indicate massive changes with the build system. Currently, Intune's Package Manager hasn't been recently updated, so I don't expect a fix besides downgrading until update.

I just updated XCode and OSX and ran the Intune MAM packager as always, but now instead of succeeding, I get this:

```
Version of MACOSX is 10.13.5
XCode prerequisite version check failed: failure in executing the xcodebuild command.
Missing prerequisite.
Cause of the error to be provided for investigation:Error Domain=IntuneAppPackager Code=22 "XCode version 5 or greater is required to run this tool." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=XCode version 5 or greater is required to run this tool.}
```

I already had to re-enable certs to match the profile, but this seems unrelated. I have the latest XCode and the build tools installed via default settings. I googled different parts of this error and nothing came back. This could be InTune's mam packager but the error itself is relatively specific in saying XCode Build tools.

Comment: I found related info with xcodebuild possibly being changed/moved and affecting this: https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/issues/902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code in your terminal:

```
xcode-select -p, then check if that path is correct path of your Xcode.
```

If this doesn't work, try this code:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /correct path of the xcode app.
```

For example:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer
```

This is what I did, and it works!

Comment: I see... you modified the build script, or its target. I should've gone lower-level than the command

Answer (score 1):

I have Xcode installed via App Store and came across the same error after switching to a new version of Intune MAM Packager.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer
```

That worked for me